# How do I make stackNavigator background transparent in react-native using 2.10.4

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I created this homeStack.js file that contains the routes. I want to use a custom background but Navigator override it and I can't seem to fix that.

This is homeStack.js

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack"
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation"
import Home from '../components/Home'
import Detail from '../components/Detail'

const screens = {
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
    },
    Detail: {
        screen: Detail
    },
}



const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false
    },
});

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

This is app.js where I try to set up my background

```
import { StyleSheet,View,ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import Navigator from './routes/homeStack'


export default function App() {
  // const image = { uri: "./assets/background.jpg" };
  const image = require( "./assets/background.jpg");


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground style={{height:"100%"}} source={image}>
      <Navigator />
      </ImageBackground>
      
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E8EAED',
  },
});
```

`I want to disable the navigator background so I can use a custom one. I was unable to turn it off.`

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach :

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const StackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
      initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Homescreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Comment: I changed the way I did navigator and I figured it out, it is really dumb made honestly.